# How to highlight lines mentioned in external program output?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, highlight

How to highlight lines mentioned in external program output ?
By external program I mean cl.exe or a program with a compatible output format.
It can be google test, lint, etc.
Using Error List and browsing those lines by F4/shift-F4 is kind of annoying when there are a lot of such lines.
I would prefer to have the lines somehow highlighted or underlined in the text editor window.